# After upgrading to 12.04 my system boots to a TTY

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm a new user to Ubuntu and I don't understand Terminal screen it tells me to enter Log-in and Password and after it tells me to type do-release-upgrade, but when I do this it says no new release found, and it seems to be no way to get out of the screen, what should I do?

Comment: You upgraded to ubuntu 12.04, but from which system?

Comment: The same is happening to me, im trying to google it but cant find anything